# Restrict Generic Kotlin Enum to certain type

Tags: kotlin, generics

I would like to enforce, at compile time, the type of a parameter to an Enum that also implements an interface:

```kotlin
interface MyInterface {
    val value: String
}

enum class WrongTypeEnum {
    WrongEnum1,
    WrongEnum2,
}

enum class CorrectTypeEnum(override val value: String) : MyInterface {
    CorrectEnum1("value1"),
    CorrectEnum2("value2");
}
```

If I write a generic function, things work correctly:

```kotlin
fun <T : Enum<out MyInterface>> myFunction(param: T) {...}

myFunction(CorrectTypeEnum.TestEnum1) // compiles successfully
myFunction(WrongTypeEnum.WrongEnum1)  // correctly shows compile error
```

Problem is that things don't work the same way if it's a generic class:

```
class MyClass<T : Enum<out MyInterface>>
// The above line shows the following compile time error:
//    Type argument is not within its bounds.
//    Expected: Enum<out MyInterface>
//    Found: MyInterface
```

So, question is: what am I doing wrong and how can I make it that `MyClass` can by typed to enum classes that also implement `MyInterface`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the syntax for class parameters is a little more convoluted:

```
class MyClass<T> where T: Enum<T>, T: MyInterface {}
```

The same syntax does also work for functions:

```
fun <T> myFunction(param: T) where T : Enum<T>, T: MyInterface {}
```

Comment: Looks like the SO Kotlin code highlighter needs an update... :D

Comment: Thank you! I've actually just flagged the highlighter issue on Kotlin issue tracker, let's hope they tackle it.

Comment: The Kotlin developers aren’t responsible for StackOverflow’s Markdown implementation, are they? Or is StackOverflow using an open source implementation where anybody can contribute?